# Wordpress and htaccess rewriterules

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to understand how to manipulate urls.

In wordpress's htaccess file I can see everything gets rewritten to index.php.
But what does that mean exactly ?
My guess is that an url request like `www.example.com/category/something/whatever` would be converted to `www.example.com?category&something&whatever`.

And you could get everything you need to display the page using php's `$_GET[]`. Am I correct?
And if so *how can I get the 'something' and 'whatever' strings?*
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens internally is that the request gets re-routed to index.php?/category/something/whatever, $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] holding the original URI. Next, the wordpress router parses the query string into url parts and url parameters, in order to know which part of the code to go to (e.g. in this case it detects that it needs to display a category page).
 If the wordpress router overwrites the superglobal $_GET variable then yes, you can access data via that variable, otherwise not. It dependes on how URI parser is implemented.
And none the less, directly accessing the $_GET contents might pose some security issues, I'd recommend delegating the access to a helper function that sanitises the input.